# Find Total Cores available for a region

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-hdinsight, cpu-cores

I need to extract total number of cores available over my subscription corresponding to region. I fired below query which returns values in terms of vCPU.

```
**az vm list-usage --location westus --output table**

**Name                                CurrentValue    Limit
-------------------------------  --------------  -------
Availability Sets                              0     2000
Total Regional vCPUs                           2       10
Virtual Machines                               1    10000
Virtual Machine Scale Sets                     0     2000
Standard B Family vCPUs                        2       10
Basic A Family vCPUs                           0       10
Standard A0-A7 Family vCPUs                    0       10
Standard A8-A11 Family vCPUs                   0       10
Standard D Family vCPUs                        0       10
Standard Dv2 Family vCPUs                      0       10**
```

Here I have created a HDInsight cluster (**with VM Size Standard_D3_V2**) with 2 headnode, 3 worker node and 3 zookeeper node. It says, it took 32 Cores.

How cores and vCPU are mapped? Also do we have any CLI 2.0 commands through which I can extract totals available cores for my subscription over any region?

I understood that, by default We have 20 cores as a limit. But in my scenario, it's 60. In this case, How can i calculate OR get that what is total numbers of core is allowed to me for any moment? because as per output of command, it shows current number of used vCPUs and limits.

Answer (score 2):

Each logical core is mapped to 1:1 to a virtual machine core.

**Example:** As you selected D3 V2 VM for head node and worker nodes, which has 4 cores, as you are selecting 2 head nodes => 2X4=8 cores, 3 worker nodes 3X4=12 cores.

And zookeeper nodes use A3 VM, which has 4 cores, as you are selecting 3 nodes 3X4=12 cores.

Total = 12+8+12 =32 cores.

[image]

**To find total cores available for a region:**

**Azure Portal:** All services => Subscriptions => Select your subscription => Usage + Quotas

[image]

**Azure PowerShell:** Get-AzureRmVMUsage -Location WestUS

[image]

**Azure CLI:** az vm list-usage –location westus –output table

[image]

**Note:** By default, Azure supports 20 cores per region, if you 20 cores you can select any VMs below 20 cores as discussed above.

If you want to raise the limit or quota above the Default Limit, [open an online customer support request at no charge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request).

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thanks Pradeep for answer. Let me re-frame my question. As you can see above, We have consumed as cores as per above table while creating a cluster. I am good that it took 32 cores.

But if i look at above table, I should have below as remaining. Total Regional vCPUs 8 Virtual Machines 9999 Virtual Machine Scale Sets 0 2000 Standard B Family vCPUs 8

But if i look at the portal, It is showing be you have only 24 cores left. I am not sure how the core calculation is being done.
Please confirm.

Comment: The vCPU quotas for virtual machines and virtual machine scale sets are arranged in two tiers for each subscription, in each region. The first tier is the Total Regional vCPUs, and the second tier is the various VM size family cores such as Standard D Family vCPUs. Any time a new VM is deployed the vCPUs for the newly deployed VM must not exceed the vCPU quota for the specific VM size family or the total regional vCPU quota. If either of those quotas are exceeded, then the VM deployment will not be allowed. There is also a quota for the overall number of virtual machines in the region.